# CSS animation not working when classname is applied in Safari

Tags: css, animation

If you view this codepen demo in Chrome and scrolldown you should see a piechart animation kick in when it comes into view. Yet in Safari Version 7.0.2 (9537.74.9) it doesn't. Any ideas why this isn't working in Safari?

http://codepen.io/s10wen/pen/czDbu

Comment: which version of Safari are you testing? `@-webkit-keyframes` is not supported in Safari 4. In my Safari 5.1.10/OsX 10.6.8 it's working

Comment: Version 7.0.2 (9537.74.9)

Comment: Here's what I'm getting in Chrome, then Safari:
https://vine.co/v/MA2pQt7Mn57

Comment: And I also noticed in Safari if I resize the viewport it also kicks in:
https://vine.co/v/MA2DeuTHODY

Comment: When making a test case, try to take out all the parts that aren't actually contributing to the bug. In this case, jQuery and waypoint are red herrings, they're not required to reproduce the issue.

Here's a (simpler) reproduction without them http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ahGdj

Comment: Additionally, I've altered the above pen to remove a lot of the CSS that wasn't required to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Safari rendering bug triggered by `backface-visibility: hidden` on the `.pie-chart > :last-child em`. That line doesn't appear to be necessary, everything works fine without it.

This example doesn't have the bug: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ktKmu.

I discovered this by removing bits of CSS & JavaScript until the bug no longer happened, revealing the single line that was causing it. Reduction ftw!